# Вызов метода delete у связанных моделей при удалении

Tags: python, django

Я храню файлы в медике django, удаление этих фалов при удалении модели прописанно в методе delete модели. Но при удалении родительской модели (каскадная связь) у дочерней модели не будет вызван метод delete и таким образом не будут удалены файлы. Можно было бы использовать сигналы, но слишком много моделей что бы сейчас описывать сигналы под них.

Может, есть какие то другие способы решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Вообще при CASCADE должны удалятся объекты по связи, подробнее бы показал,

Comment: @attreButtoN да, они удаляются, но в методе delete у меня описано удаление файлов, так же при удалении модели, в дочерней модели в методе delete не останавливается дебаг

Comment: Посмотри за Django-cleanup он типо чистит неиспользуемые файлы, а так только сигналом насколько мне известно, @Kola_narushev

Comment: @attreButtoN большое спасибо, попробывал и пошло поехало, а то с сигналами пару раз уже проблемы были и не хотелось их использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помог пользователь @attreButtoN и библиотека Django-cleanup
Но есть одно НО, данная библиотека работает на сигналах, что является антипаттерном, поэтому в после её дальнейшего изучения пришлось от неё отказаться

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]